# find out if input is a float, if not, append it to a dictionary

Tags: python

```
my_dictionary = {"City":[], "Number":[]}
while True:
    city = input("City: ")
    if city == "":
        break
    try:
        while int(city) == True:
            print("You entered a number instead of a city name")
            city = input("Input city name again: ")
    except ValueError:
        my_dictionary["City"].append(city)
    number = input("Number: ")
    if number == "":
        break
    **try:
        if int(number) == True and int(number) > 0:
            my_dictionary["Number"].append(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("You entered a float instead of an integer")
        number = input("Input an integer: ")
print(my_dictionary)**
```

Hi, I have a little problem with the highlighted part. I want to make the input so that it is restricted to integers only.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `int(<number>) == True` to check if it's an integer, but the `int()` function will only ever return integers, or raise exceptions, so that's not the right way to do it.

If you want to check if something can be converted to an int, you can do

```py
try:
  foo = int(foo)
  # foo can be converted to an int, so do code here
except ValueError:
  # foo cannot be converted to an int, so do code here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to ask: if the "user" tries to input a float after the "warning", I would like to show them the warning again and not let them further. Do you have any idea how to make this?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `number.isnumeric()` to check if your number is an int. You can change your try and except block to this:

```
if number.lstrip("-").isnumeric() and int(number) > 0:
    my_dictionary["Number"].append(number)
else:
    print("You entered a float instead of an integer")
    number = input("Input an integer: ")
```

Comment: This is not correct - number is never converted to an integer, so it will always return false.

Comment: Negative numbers don't work with `isnumeric`, that's one thing to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `type()`. It can be used to check for any kind of data type. For example `type(list), type(object), type(int), ect...`

```
i = 1.000000000001
if type(i) is float:
 print(type(i))
```

Comment: This isn't wrong per se, but it doesn't answer the question.
There are no float values anywhere in the code, the question is for if the string can be converted as an integer, or not (float/letters etc)

Comment: @AlexApps99 OP understands conversion as it's in his code already. The example above is a LBYL solution to OPs problem.

Comment: Nowhere in OP's code do they convert to a float, so this example isn't really relevant - it's not LBYL because it assumes that `i` has already been safely converted to a `float` without checking if you can or not.